# Kotlin: Modify property of list object

Tags: android, loops, kotlin, gson, mutablelist

What is the expressive way to update/modify a property of object in a MutableList?

```
data class Car(
    var imageUri: Uri,
    var description: String = ""
   )
```

I want the `imageUri` value to be empty at some point while retaining its description, so this is what I tried.

```
Gson().toJson(carList.map { it.imageUri = Uri.EMPTY }) //Clear image URI of all car
```

But the list becomes empty when converting it to JSON String representation with Gson.

```
 "[{},{}]"
```

I could do this approach but not sure if its the best.

```
carList.map { Gson().toJson(Car(Uri.EMPTY, it.description)) }.toString()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `forEach` function to iterate through each element of the list and change property of every element. For example:

```
carList.forEach { it.imageUri = Uri.EMPTY }
Gson().toJson(carList)
```

Another option is `onEach`:

```
Gson().toJson(carList.onEach { it.imageUri = Uri.EMPTY })
```

The difference between them is that the `onEach` function returns the collection itself after performing the given action on each element, and `forEach` doesn't.

Comment: also the reason ``map`` doesn't work is it's transforming each element of ``carList`` into the result of the lambda expression. But the lambda is performing an action, it isn't returning anything (so it returns ``Unit`` instead). ``map`` = create a new collection by transforming each element into something else, ``forEach`` = do something with each item in a collection